# Tweened animation with Paper.js

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, tween, paperjs

I want to be able to define tweened animations using Paper.js. So far I have determined that Tween.js would probably be the best library to use for this. However I don't see any examples on the web, all of them seem to be for Three.js.

Does anyone have other suggestions for how I might achieve tweened animations? I am trying to animate some paths on mouseMove() mouseDown() and mouseUp() events.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are a few examples of how to use Tween.js with Paper.js:

- A very simple example of [moving a star](http://yomotsu.net/blog/assets/2013-03-15-createjs/demo2/index.html) without interaction.
- A **tutorial** article on creating a nice [jelly effect](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/15/jelly-navigation-menu-canvas-paperjs/) which heavily uses mouses and scrolling velocity.
- A [complex multipart animation](http://codepen.io/sol0mka/pen/iHtsL) on CodePen that uses mouseOver as a trigger.

Here's the relevant code snippet on the paperjs + tweenjs integration from the first example.

```js
 path.position = {
    x : 100,
    y : 100
  }

  createjs.Tween.get( path.position, { loop: true } )
  .to( { x: 300 }, 1000, createjs.Ease.quadOut )
  .wait( 2000 )
  .to( { x: 100, y: 300 }, 1000, createjs.Ease.quadOut )
  .wait( 2000 )
  .to( { x: 100, y: 100 }, 1000, createjs.Ease.quadOut )
  .wait( 2000 )
  .call( function() {
    console.log( 'done!' );
  } );

  var update = function() {
    paper.view.draw();
  }

  createjs.Ticker.setFPS( 60 );
  createjs.Ticker.addEventListener( 'tick', update );
```